# Dataset.reduce doesn't support shorthand function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a simple code:

```
test("0153") {
  val c = Seq(1,8,4,2,7)
  val max = (x:Int, y:Int)=> if (x > y) x else y
  c.reduce(max)
}
```

It works fine. But, when I follow the same way to use `Dataset.reduce`,

```
test("SparkSQLTest") {
  def max(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) x else y
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLTest").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  val ds = spark.range(1, 100).map(_.toInt)
  ds.reduce(max) //compiling error:Error:(20, 15) missing argument list for method max
}
```

Compiler complains that `missing argument list for method max`, I don't what's going on here.

Comment: ds.reduce((x, y) => max(x,y)) should work

Comment: Does `ds.reduce(max _)` work?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to a function instead of a method and it should work, i.e. instead of

```
def max(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) x else y
```

use

```
val max = (x: Int, y: Int) => if (x > y) x else y
```

Using the function, using `ds.reduce(max)` should work directly. More about the differences can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

---

Otherwise, as hadooper pointed out you can use the method by supplying the arguments,

```
def max(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) x else y
ds.reduce((x, y) => max(x,y))
```

Comment: @hadooper: No problems :)

Comment: That‘s interesting, Thanks @Shaido

Answer (score 1):

As per spark scala doc, reduce function signature is [reduce(func: ReduceFunction[T]): T](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@reduce(func:org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[T]):T) and [reduce(func: (T, T) ⇒ T): T](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@reduce(func:(T,T)=%3ET):T) So either of the following will work

**Approach 1:**

```
scala> val ds = spark.range(1, 100).map(_.toInt)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> def max(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) x else y
max: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> ds.reduce((x, y) => max(x,y))
res1: Int = 99
```

**Approach 2 [If you insist on short hand notation like reduce(max)]:**

```
scala> val ds = spark.range(1, 100).map(_.toInt)
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> object max extends org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[Int]{
     | def call(x:Int, y:Int) = {if (x > y) x else y}
     | }
defined object max

scala> ds.reduce(max)
res3: Int = 99
```

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Thanks @hadooper. The 2nd approach is more like using Java API. For 1st approach, I don't understand why `ds.reduce(max)` doesn't work